# Show that $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha + \beta) = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am looking for help in proving that:
$\mathbf{Q}(\alpha + \beta) = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$,
where $\mathbf{Q}(X)$ denotes the field of rational numbers adjoin $X$. Is it enough to quote the Primitive Element Theorem?

$\alpha, \beta$ are elements of distinct extension fields of $\mathbf{Q}$. That is to say, the extensions are such that $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)\cap\mathbf{Q}(\beta) = \mathbf{Q}$. Apologies for any confusing regarding the use of 'distinct', I hope the clarification helps.

Comment: What are $\alpha$ and $\beta$?  You'll have a problem if they're transcendental.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Do you even need them transcendental for problems? What about $\alpha=2-\sqrt{2}$ and $\beta=\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Also, you'll have problems if $\alpha=-\beta$ (or something similar).

Comment: @Git Gud These examples are invalid. If $\alpha = -\beta$ then they lie in the same extension. Consider distinct extension fields of $\mathbf{Q}$

Comment: What about $\alpha=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ and $\beta=-\sqrt{2}$?  The extensions are different, but the equality doesn't hold.

Comment: @user1654733 You are correct, I misread the edit. (I removed my comment).

Comment: @Micheal Burr in this instance $\mathbf{Q}(\beta) \subset \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$. Again, this is an invalid example as these are not distinct extensions.

Comment: Ok, that's not how I would interpret distinct extensions.  Perhaps you should clarify to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\cap\mathbb{Q}(\beta)=\mathbb{Q}$ *and* that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic.

Comment: Also, the word "arbitrary" is a bit confusing.  Different elements of an extension can generate different fields.  Perhaps just drop that word.

Comment: @OP Please don't ignore needing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ algebraic.  It is definitely NOT the case that $\Bbb{Q}(x,y)=\Bbb{Q}(x+y)$ when $x$ and $y$ are indeterminates. They don't even have the same transcendence degree.

Comment: The proof of the primitive element theorem usually shows that $\alpha+c\beta$ is primitive for some $c\in\Bbb Q$. There's a reason why the proof does not simply try $c=1$.

Comment: I am upvoting this question because I don't understand why it was downvoted.  Yes, it was a little confused.  What's the point of people being able to ask questions if they can't ask them when they're confused?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Spot on.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general (even with the assumption of trivial intersection in place).

Consider the case of $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/3}\root3\of2$, one of the complex zeros of $p(x)=x^3-2$. Let $\beta=\overline{\alpha}$. Then $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$ are two distinct cubic extensions, and hence they intersect trivially. Here $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ is the splitting field of $p(x)$, a degree six extension.

On the other hand $\alpha+\beta=-\root3\of2$ generates only a cubic extension.

Answer (score 1):

The primitive element theorem tells you that there is a primitive element. It does not say that $\alpha+\beta$ is a primitive element, and this is what you are trying to prove.

There is a reason that then primitive element theorem does not go via $\alpha+\beta$, which is that it is not that simple - as even the simple counter-examples to your unedited question show, some care needs to be taken.

If you wanted to ask a related question, you might ask for necessary and sufficient criteria for $\alpha+\beta$ to be a primitive element - which is what you have been working towards with your edits.

But to answer your primary question again, it is insufficient to quote the primitive element theorem to achieve what you want.

Comment: And some criterion about extensions being algebraic (which seems to be assumed but not stated) is, as comments suggest, essential. Clarity of expression is required here as well as clarity of thought.